# Thymeleaf: use the same template with dynamic url from different controllers

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

I have two html templates which do same function, but handled by two different controllers:

1st html handled by moderator controller

```
<form th:action="@{/moderator/new-user-form}" th:object="${caltest}" method="post"
     enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-validate form row">
    <!-- some code -->
</form>
```

2nd html handled by admin controller

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/new-user-form}" th:object="${caltest}" method="post"
     enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-validate form row">
    <!-- some code -->
</form>
```

As you can see these templates differ only by `action` url:

```
th:action="@{/someurl}"
```

**Is it possible to use the same template with dynamic url from different controllers?**

Comment: I am asking this question to avoid repeating the same code many times

Comment: from where do you get the identifier to call the right controller? In your case `admin` or `moderator`? Or at least the full url?

Comment: Have you tried that? Did you get any errors? The Same template can be returned from different controllers as long as they are mapped to different URL paths

Comment: @SAP yes I am using that now without any errors. My urls differ, since each controller is mapped accordingly(For instance: /admin/save-user-form, /moderator/save-user-form)

Comment: @Patrick this is how exactly I am getting url in my project:      
`@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AdminController {
//some other code
@RequestMapping("/submit-murojaat")
    public String newMurojat(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("caltest", new Caltest());
        model.addAttribute("action", "/save-new-murojaat");
        return "murojaatNewS";
    }
}`

Comment: Sorry for ugly comment. I don't know how to give new line in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this...  the simplest, is to use the same template in the controllers, and in each controller pass a variable that contains the correct action.

For example:

```
// Moderator controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/moderator")
public String moderator(Map<String, Object> model) {
  model.put("action", "/moderator/new-user-form");
  return "new-user-form";
}

// Admin controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/moderator")
public String moderator(Map<String, Object> model) {
  model.put("action", "/admin/new-user-form");
  return "new-user-form";
}
```

And in the html

```
<form th:action="@{${action}}">
```

If that isn't suitable, you could turn the form itself into a fragment, and then pass the action as a parameter.  Something like this:

```
<!-- Fragment -->
<form th:fragment="userform (action)" th:action="@{${action}}">
  .
  .
  .
</form>

<!-- Including the fragment -->
<div th:replace="fragments/userform :: userform(action='/admin/new-user-form')" />
<!-- or -->
<div th:replace="fragments/userform :: userform(action='/moderator/new-user-form')" />
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! `<form th:action="@{${action}}">` Thank you so much!